# In Jetpack Compose screens overlaps, or partially rendered, when being navigated with Jetpack Compose navigation controller

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, jetpack-compose-navigation, jetpack

I have tried to disable Animation still my Screen Partially rendered at initial stage at time of navigation and popBackStack navigation too

```
@Composable
fun OwnerProfileNavigation(
    navController: NavHostController,
    startDestination: String
) {

    val screen = remember(navController) {
        OwnerProfileScreens(navController = navController)
    }
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = startDestination,
        enterTransition = {
            EnterTransition.None

        },
        popExitTransition = { ExitTransition.None},
        exitTransition = {
            ExitTransition.None
        },


    ) {
        ownerProfileScreen(navigateToDriverScreen = screen.ownerProfile)
        ownerToDriver()



    }

}
```

This my NavHost where I am generating the graph.
For Better Clarity I am Attaching a clip for the reference
Thankyou In Advance
[image: Issue]

Comment: Please help anybody??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jetpack Compose, by default, has a fade-out-fade-in transition when navigating between two screens. If you are encountering issues like this, it could be due to the absence of a background applied to each Compose screen. The default Modifier renders these screens with a transparent surface. During the fade-out-fade-in effect, the content of the upcoming screen may appear before the outgoing screen is entirely hidden. **To resolve this, consider using a background modifier on your Compose screens with the desired background colour.**

Comment: I applied color to my Column that worked cool!! Thankyou So much!!